# Vaadin and Spring with Touchkit. servlet and annotation based?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-boot, vaadin

I have a fully working spring and vaadin application based off spring boot. The application class has now been modified to create a custom servlet so I can use both touchkit and spring within the project as such.

I have been following this git project to perform this:[git project example](https://github.com/mstahv/vaadin-spring-touchkit/tree/master/src/main/java/org/vaadin/tkspring)

```
public class SmartenderApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SmartenderApplication.class, args);
}

@Bean
public VaadinServlet vaadinServlet() {
    return new SpringAwareTouchKitServlet();
}}
```

I modified the custom servlet to follow the vaadin docs for using a UI provider to choose between the touchkit UI and the browswer fallback UI as so

```
public class SpringAwareTouchKitServlet extends SpringVaadinServlet {

    TouchKitSettings touchKitSettings;
    MyUIProvider prov = new MyUIProvider();

    @Override
    protected void servletInitialized() throws ServletException {
        super.servletInitialized();
        getService().addSessionInitListener(
                new SessionInitListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void sessionInit(SessionInitEvent event)
                            throws ServiceException {
                        event.getSession().addUIProvider(prov);
                    }
                });

        touchKitSettings = new TouchKitSettings(getService());
    }
}

class MyUIProvider extends UIProvider {
    @Override
    public Class<? extends UI>
    getUIClass(UIClassSelectionEvent event) {
        String ua = event.getRequest()
                .getHeader("user-agent").toLowerCase();
        if (   ua.toLowerCase().contains("ios")) {
            return myTouchkitUI.class;
        } else {
            return myUI.class;
        }
    }
}
```

My application works when I do not call this section of code to choose a UI provider. But it will always go to a touchkit UI. :

```
    getService().addSessionInitListener(
            new SessionInitListener() {
                @Override
                public void sessionInit(SessionInitEvent event)
                        throws ServiceException {
                    event.getSession().addUIProvider(prov);
                }
            });
```

My issue is that although it will choose between which UI class to return as soon as it begins to progress through the chosen UI code it passes back null objects that were originally autowired through spring. Seeing as this works when i dont choose a UI and just goes for touchkit, im assuming it must be somewhere in my UI provider choice code thats stopping the Spring functionality from allowing my classes to autowire, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the UIProvider is supposed to manage UI instances. Furthermore, since you're using Spring (Boot or not) it should retrieve beans from the Spring context instead of creating the instances itself when one is necessary:

[**`UIProvider`**](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin/blob/master/server/src/com/vaadin/server/UIProvider.java) / [**`DefaultUIProvider`**](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin/blob/master/server/src/com/vaadin/server/DefaultUIProvider.java):

```java
public UI createInstance(UICreateEvent event) {
    try {
        return event.getUIClass().newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not instantiate UI class", e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not access UI class", e);
    }
}
```

Thus, I'd say that instead of extending the simple [`UIProvider`](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin/blob/master/server/src/com/vaadin/server/UIProvider.java) (or rather the [`DefaultUIProvider`](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin/blob/master/server/src/com/vaadin/server/DefaultUIProvider.java)) you should extend the [`SpringUIProvider`](https://github.com/vaadin/spring/blob/master/vaadin-spring/src/main/java/com/vaadin/spring/server/SpringUIProvider.java), which retrieves instances from your app's Spring context, so the automagic will begin to happen again.

[**`SpringUIProvider`**](https://github.com/vaadin/spring/blob/master/vaadin-spring/src/main/java/com/vaadin/spring/server/SpringUIProvider.java):

```java
@Override
public UI createInstance(UICreateEvent event) {
    final Class<UIID> key = UIID.class;
    final UIID identifier = new UIID(event);
    CurrentInstance.set(key, identifier);
    try {
        logger.debug(
                "Creating a new UI bean of class [{}] with identifier [{}]",
                event.getUIClass().getCanonicalName(), identifier);
        return webApplicationContext.getBean(event.getUIClass());
    } finally {
        CurrentInstance.set(key, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: `class MyUIProvider extends SpringUIProvider {

 public MyUIProvider(WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext) {
  super(webApplicationContext);
 }

 @Override
 public UI createInstance(UICreateEvent event) {
 ...} `

I have been forced to add a web application context into the constructor for this to work, but i do not actually have a web application context xml file. I am using annotation based only so I do not know where to pull my web application context from for this to work? sorry if this if i am being silly here.

Comment: @jimmyboix You're not silly, it's a perfectly valid question. Since you're extending the [SpringVaadinServlet](https://github.com/vaadin/spring/blob/master/vaadin-spring/src/main/java/com/vaadin/spring/server/SpringVaadinServlet.java), why not take a look at what it does in its `servletInitialized()` method and simply do the same? :-)